# Pivot in Linq-want to show dates from date range as column names in linq query

Tags: linq

Below is my code:

```
  var dataQuery = (from p in DB.TProject
     join c in DB.TClient on p.ProjectId equals c.ProjectId
     join ct in DB.TContract on c.ClientId equals ct.ClientId
     join cp in DB.TClientPortfolio on ct.ContractId equals cp.ContractId
     join pb in DB.TPortfolioBucket on cp.ClientPortfolioId equals pb.ClientPortfolioId into pbcp
     from pb in pbcp.DefaultIfEmpty()
     join pf in DB.TPortfolioFrequency on cp.PortfolioFrequencyId equals pf.PortfolioFrequencyId
     join f in (from cpi in DB.TClientPortfolioIsin
                where cpi.IsActive
                group cpi by cpi.ClientPortfolioId into grp1
                select new
                {
                    ClientPortfolioId = grp1.Key,
                    ISIN_Count = grp1.Count()
                }
     ) on cp.ClientPortfolioId equals f.ClientPortfolioId into isin
     from f in isin.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new ClientMISReport
     {
         ProjectCode = p.ProjectCode,
         ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
         ClientName = c.ClientName,
         StartDate = ct.StartDate,
         EndDate = ct.EndDate
     }).Distinct();
```

In the above code want add dates as column name and with respect to that will show the time from another table.

Comment: What type would you expect the result to be? What column names do you have now?

Comment: Unfortunately PIVOT/UNPIVOT queries is not what LINQ can do in current known realisations.